# Angular Route Resolve -- Invoking Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Using angular `ngRoute`, I am routing request to different views/controllers. I would like to take advantage of the functionality to delay completing a route until some set of pre-requisite futures are completed.

I am using the following syntax:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/users', {
    templateUrl: 'user-view.html',
    controller: 'UserController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
      users: function(userDataService) {
        // returns a future
        return userDataService.loadUsers();
      }
    }
  })
```

This is a simple use-case, where we simply ask `UserDataService` to load the value for `users` before passing it to the controller's constructor. All good.

---

In reality, the initialization of my controllers is far more complicated than this. Rather that injecting `users` into the controller, I'd rather inject the `UserDataService` and have the initialization completed in `UserController.init()`.

This code illustrates my desires:

```
angular.controller('UserController', ['UserDataService', function(userDataService) {

  this.userDataService = userDataService;
  this.users = [];
  this.currentUser = null
  this.otherUsersInMyGroup = [];
  this.supervisedUsers = [];

  this.init() {
    // Return a "joined" promise that aggregates each promise
    return $q.all([

      this.userDataService.loadUsers()
      .then(function (u) { this.users = u }.bind(this)),

      this.userDataService.getCurrentUser()
      .then(function (u) { this.currentUser = u }.bind(this)),

      // ... Other load promises for other members

    ]);

  }

  return this;

}]);
```

This means I now need to be able to delay the route completion until the `UserController.init()` method is complete.

How is this compatible with the `resolve` approach in the router?

Given the `resolve` functionality is aimed at providing parameters to the controller's constructor, it's a bit of a chicken-and-egg situation... The controller must be created before I can call `controller.init()`, but the resolve mathods are evaluated before the controller is created, so the constructor parameters may be inejcted.

Comment: Why can't you do it in userService and use normal resolve?

Comment: @dfsq In the example I would have to resolve 4 different members, and for complex controllers that list could grow quite large. The router does not feel like the correct place for this set-up logic to be.... philosophically,  it's not a function of routing, but of the controller itself.